# Weird early EOF termination of Forward() parser_element

Tags: python, pyparsing

After perusing and debugging several `Forward()` features in `pyparsing` examples, I've cobbled several of these feature sets together as needed for the ISC Bind9/DHCP configuration file:

- Pushing/poppping an '!' symbol into the execStack
- `Forward()`
- Reusing `parsing_common.ipv4_address`

There is one EBNF (detailed in this [Zytrax link](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/address_match_list.html)) that I am struggling here:

```
address_match_list = element ; [ element; ... ]

element = [!] (ip [/prefix] | key key-name | "acl_name" | { address_match_list } )
```

My final (but failing best-fit) draft is:

```py
element = Forward()
element <<= (
    # Hide the exclamation so we can do deeper parse cleaner w/o clutter of '!'
    (0, None) * Word('!') +

    # Might be nice to do a bit of lookahead for '.', ':', 'key', and '"'
    # | is matchFirst, not matchLongest
    # ^ is matchLongest
    (
        ZeroOrMore(
            (
                # Typical pattern "1.2.3.4/24;"
                (
                    Combine(
                        pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + '/' + Word(nums, max=3)
                    ) + ';'
                ) ^                                        # Start: '999.999.999.999/99'
                # Typical pattern "2.3.4.5;"
                (pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + ';') ^    # Start: '999.999.999.999'
                # Typical pattern "3210::1;"
                (pyparsing_common.ipv6_address + ';') ^    # Start: 'XXXX:'
                (Keyword('key') + Word(alphanums, max=63) + ';')
                                                           # Start: 'key <key-varname>'
            )
        ) ^
        # Typical pattern "{ 1.2.3.4; };"
        ZeroOrMore('{' - element + '}' + ';')
    ).setParseAction(pushFirst)
).setParseAction(pushExclamation)
```

And I ran the `element.runTests()`:

```py
element.runTests('2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };')
2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };
         ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)
```

the unexpected 'expected EOF' after matching first element is what is stopping the entire parser.

Working standalone snippet of code that demonstrates the problem.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# EBNF detailed at http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/address_match_list.html
from pyparsing import *
exprStack = []

def pushFirst(strg, loc, toks):
    exprStack.append(toks[0])

def pushExclamation(strg, loc, toks):
    for t in toks:
        if t == '!':
            exprStack.append('!')
        else:
            break

# Address_Match_List (AML)
# This AML combo is ordered very carefully so that longest pattern are tried firstly
#
# EBNF reiterated here:
#
#    address_match_list = element ; [ element; ... ]
#
#    element = [!] (ip [/prefix] | key key-name | "acl_name" | { address_match_list } )
#
element = Forward()
element <<= (
    # Hide the exclamation so we can do deeper parse cleaner w/o clutter of '!'
    (0, None) * Word('!') +

    # Might be nice to do a bit of lookahead for '.', ':', 'key', and '"'
    # | is matchFirst, not matchLongest
    # ^ is matchLongest
    (
        ZeroOrMore(
            (
                # Typical pattern "1.2.3.4/24;"
                (
                    Combine(
                        pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + '/' + Word(nums, max=3)
                    ) + ';'
                ) ^                                        # Start: '999.999.999.999/99'
                # Typical pattern "2.3.4.5;"
                (pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + ';') ^    # Start: '999.999.999.999'
                # Typical pattern "3210::1;"
                (pyparsing_common.ipv6_address + ';') ^    # Start: 'XXXX:'
                (
                    Keyword('key') + Word(alphanums, max=63) + ';'
                )                                          # Start: 'key <key-variable-name>'
            )
        ) ^
        # Typical pattern "{ 1.2.3.4; };"
        ZeroOrMore('{' + element + '}' + ';')
    ).setParseAction(pushFirst)
).setParseAction(pushExclamation)
element.setName('"element ;"')
element.setDebug()

result = element.runTests("""
123.123.123.123;
!210.210.210.210;
{ 234.234.234.234 };
2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };
{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;
{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;
!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };
12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;
14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;
17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key; }
""")

import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
print("Result: ")
pp.pprint(result)
```

### Test Run of Valid Syntax Contents

Complete `element.runTests()` output:

```
123.123.123.123;
['123.123.123.123', ';']

!210.210.210.210;
['!', '210.210.210.210', ';']

{ 234.234.234.234 };
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };
         ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)

{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;
              ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '5'  (at char 14), (line:1, col:15)

{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;
                       ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '8'  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)

!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };
['!', '{', '9.9.9.9', ';', '10.10.10.10', ';', '}', ';']

12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;
             ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '!'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)

14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;
['14.14.14.14/15', ';', '16.16.16.16', ';', 'key', 'MySha512Key', ';']

17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key; }
                ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 16), (line:1, col:17)
```

Pretty-printed result is:

```
Result: 
(   False,
    [   ('123.123.123.123;', (['123.123.123.123', ';'], {})),
        ('!210.210.210.210;', (['!', '210.210.210.210', ';'], {})),
        (   '{ 234.234.234.234 };',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };',
            Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)),
        (   '{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;',
            Expected end of text, found '5'  (at char 14), (line:1, col:15)),
        (   '{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;',
            Expected end of text, found '8'  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)),
        (   '!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };',
            (['!', '{', '9.9.9.9', ';', '10.10.10.10', ';', '}', ';'], {})),
        (   '12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;',
            Expected end of text, found '!'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)),
        (   '14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;',
            (['14.14.14.14/15', ';', '16.16.16.16', ';', 'key', 'MySha512Key', ';'], {})),
        (   '17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key; }',
            Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 16), (line:1, col:17))])

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm still debugging slowly on the `234.234.234.234;` and `3.3.3.3;`so I would hope that someone would glance and say 'there it is' while I slowly debug this.

### Test Run of Purposely-Failed Syntax

UPDATED:  Added test code of purposely failed syntax contents:

```py
result = element.runTests("""
20
!
key;
21;
{ 23 };
{ 24.24.24.24 };
{ 25.25.25.25; }
26.26.26.26
27.27.27.27; key
28.28.28.28; { key }
29.29.29.29, 30.30.30.30;
{ 31.31.31.31; 32.32.32.32; }
{ 33.33.33.33; 34.34.34.34; }; 35;
""", failureTests=True)
print("Result of failed contents: ")
pp.pprint(result)
```

Test run of failed content (pretty-print-format):

```
Result of failed contents: 
(   True,
    [   ('20', exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        ('!', exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   'key;',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        ('21;', exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '{ 23 };',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '{ 24.24.24.24 };',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '{ 25.25.25.25; }',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '26.26.26.26',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '27.27.27.27; key',
            Expected end of text, found 'k'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)),
        (   '28.28.28.28; { key }',
            Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)),
        (   '29.29.29.29, 30.30.30.30;',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '{ 31.31.31.31; 32.32.32.32; }',
            exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)),
        (   '{ 33.33.33.33; 34.34.34.34; }; 35;',
            Expected end of text, found '3'  (at char 31), (line:1, col:32))])

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

20
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

!
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

key;
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

21;
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Match "element ;" at loc 1(1,2)
Matched "element ;" -> []
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

{ 23 };
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Match "element ;" at loc 1(1,2)
Matched "element ;" -> []
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

{ 24.24.24.24 };
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Match "element ;" at loc 1(1,2)
Matched "element ;" -> ['25.25.25.25', ';']
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

{ 25.25.25.25; }
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

26.26.26.26
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Matched "element ;" -> ['27.27.27.27', ';']

27.27.27.27; key
             ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found 'k'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Matched "element ;" -> ['28.28.28.28', ';']

28.28.28.28; { key }
             ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '{'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

29.29.29.29, 30.30.30.30;
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Match "element ;" at loc 1(1,2)
Matched "element ;" -> ['31.31.31.31', ';', '32.32.32.32', ';']
Exception raised:exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

{ 31.31.31.31; 32.32.32.32; }
^
FAIL: exception raised in parse action  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Match "element ;" at loc 1(1,2)
Matched "element ;" -> ['33.33.33.33', ';', '34.34.34.34', ';']
Match "element ;" at loc 1(1,2)
Matched "element ;" -> ['33.33.33.33', ';', '34.34.34.34', ';']
Matched "element ;" -> ['{', '33.33.33.33', ';', '34.34.34.34', ';', '}', ';']

{ 33.33.33.33; 34.34.34.34; }; 35;
                               ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '3'  (at char 31), (line:1, col:
```

### UPDATE: From the answer provided by Paul MacG, I've updated the snippet of code with his suggestion.

Before I get to that, I've found two more error in my two test runs (valid syntax and invalid syntax); both errors were in the valid syntax test run.  I've updated the test snippet as:

```py
result = element.runTests("""
123.123.123.123;
!210.210.210.210;
{ 234.234.234.234; };
2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };
{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;
{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;
!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };
12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;
14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;
17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key;
""")
print("Result of valid contents: ")
pp.pprint(result)
```

Now the test result is narrowed down to just one failing syntax:

```
Result of valid contents: 
(   False,
    [   ('123.123.123.123;', (['123.123.123.123', ';'], {})),
        ('!210.210.210.210;', (['!', '210.210.210.210', ';'], {})),
        (   '{ 234.234.234.234; };',
            ([(['{', '234.234.234.234', ';', '}', ';'], {})], {})),
        (   '2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };',
            (['2.2.2.2', ';', (['{', '3.3.3.3', ';', '}', ';'], {})], {})),
        (   '{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;',
            ([(['{', '4.4.4.4', ';', '}', ';'], {}), '5.5.5.5', ';'], {})),
        (   '{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;',
            ([(['{', '6.6.6.6', ';', '7.7.7.7', ';', '}', ';'], {}), '8.8.8.8', ';'], {})),
        (   '!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };',
            (['!', (['{', '9.9.9.9', ';', '10.10.10.10', ';', '}', ';'], {})], {})),
        (   '12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;',
            Expected end of text, found '!'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)),
        (   '14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;',
            (['14.14.14.14/15', ';', '16.16.16.16', ';', 'key', 'MySha512Key', ';'], {})),
        (   '17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key;',
            (['17.17.17.17/18', ';', (['{', '19.19.19.19', ';', '}', ';'], {}), 'key', 'YourSha512Key', ';'], {}))])
```

This is a major step forward.

I've noticed the following fundamental changes:

- introduction of `delimitedList()`
- the `ZeroOrMore` got consolidated within the `Forward()`

We are left with one error pertaining to an exclamation mark used in nested `element`.

```py
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
result = element.runTests("""
12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;
""")
print("Result of valid contents: ")
pp.pprint(result)
```

Test Result is:

```
Match "element ;" at loc 0(1,1)
Matched "element ;" -> ['12.12.12.12', ';']

12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;
             ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '!'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)
Result of valid contents: 
(   False,
    [   (   '12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;',
            Expected end of text, found '!'  (at char 13), (line:1, col:14))])
```

### Final Run of a Working Solution

In the final test code, I've incorporated Paul McG's suggestion of pushing the exclamation parser_element to inside the `ZeroOrMore` as shown below:

```py
# Address_Match_List (AML)
# This AML combo is ordered very carefully so that longest pattern are tried firstly
#
# EBNF reiterated here:
#
#    address_match_list = element ; [ element; ... ]
#
#    element = [!] (ip [/prefix] | key key-name | "acl_name" | { address_match_list } )
#
element = Forward()
element <<= (
    # Might be nice to do a bit of lookahead for '.', ':', 'key', and '"'
    # | is matchFirst, not matchLongest
    # ^ is matchLongest
    ZeroOrMore(
        # Hide the exclamation so we can do deeper parse cleaner w/o clutter of '!'
        (0, None) * Word('!') +
        (
                (
                        (Combine(pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + '/' + Word(nums, max=3)) + ';')
                        ^ (pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + ';')
                        ^ (pyparsing_common.ipv6_address + ';')
                        ^ (Keyword('key') + Word(alphanums, max=63) + ';')
                        ^ Keyword('acl_name')
                ).setParseAction(pushFirst)
                ^ Group('{' - delimitedList(element, delim=';') + '}' + ';')
        )
    )
).setParseAction(pushExclamation)
element.setName('"element ;"')
element.setDebug()

import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
result = element.runTests("""
123.123.123.123;
!210.210.210.210;
{ 234.234.234.234; };
2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };
{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;
{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;
!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };
12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;
14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;
17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key;
""")
print("Result of valid contents: ")
pp.pprint(result)
```

As a result of the test run above, its test result of valid syntax contents is:

```
Result of valid contents: 
(   True,
    [   ('123.123.123.123;', (['123.123.123.123', ';'], {})),
        ('!210.210.210.210;', (['!', '210.210.210.210', ';'], {})),
        (   '{ 234.234.234.234; };',
            ([(['{', '234.234.234.234', ';', '}', ';'], {})], {})),
        (   '2.2.2.2; { 3.3.3.3; };',
            (['2.2.2.2', ';', (['{', '3.3.3.3', ';', '}', ';'], {})], {})),
        (   '{ 4.4.4.4; }; 5.5.5.5;',
            ([(['{', '4.4.4.4', ';', '}', ';'], {}), '5.5.5.5', ';'], {})),
        (   '{ 6.6.6.6; 7.7.7.7; }; 8.8.8.8;',
            ([(['{', '6.6.6.6', ';', '7.7.7.7', ';', '}', ';'], {}), '8.8.8.8', ';'], {})),
        (   '!{ 9.9.9.9; 10.10.10.10; };',
            (['!', (['{', '9.9.9.9', ';', '10.10.10.10', ';', '}', ';'], {})], {})),
        (   '12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;',
            (['12.12.12.12', ';', '!', '13.13.13.13', ';'], {})),
        (   '14.14.14.14/15; 16.16.16.16; key MySha512Key;',
            (['14.14.14.14/15', ';', '16.16.16.16', ';', 'key', 'MySha512Key', ';'], {})),
        (   '17.17.17.17/18; { 19.19.19.19; }; key YourSha512Key;',
            (['17.17.17.17/18', ';', (['{', '19.19.19.19', ';', '}', ';'], {}), 'key', 'YourSha512Key', ';'], {}))])
```

Wow.  The answer below fixed the problem.  Need to grapple it some more so I can give a better summary as to the "why".

Now it's easy skating to the filling out rest of ISC-style configuration.

Comment: I left out the `Group()` of each `element` so that I can get the basic of `Forward()` working correctly and firstly.

Comment: What is the purpose of the stack? And of the tests passed to runTests, which ones are supposed to pass and which one to fail? If you have some intentional failure tests, you can break this up into two calls to runTests, one with passing tests and one with failing tests, and pass `failureTests=True` in the second.

Comment: All the entries given in the initial posting inside `element.runTests()` are intended to be valid parseable content.  I'll draft a few `failureTests=True` next.

Comment: For those curious where all this is store at in here:  https://github.com/egberts/bind9_parser/blob/master/bind9_parser/isc_aml.py

Comment: And the unittest code for Bind9 Address Match List (AML):  https://github.com/egberts/bind9_parser/blob/master/tests/test_aml.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you closer, but I'm not sure it is doing the stack bits correctly.

```
element = Forward()
element <<= (
    # Hide the exclamation so we can do deeper parse cleaner w/o clutter of '!'
    (0, None) * Word('!') +

    # Might be nice to do a bit of lookahead for '.', ':', 'key', and '"'
    # | is matchFirst, not matchLongest
    # ^ is matchLongest
    ZeroOrMore(
        (
            (Combine(pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + '/' + Word(nums, max=3)) + ';')
            ^ (pyparsing_common.ipv4_address + ';')
            ^ (pyparsing_common.ipv6_address + ';')
            ^ (Keyword('key') + Word(alphanums, max=63) + ';')
            ^ Keyword('acl_name')
        ).setParseAction(pushFirst)
        ^ Group('{' - delimitedList(element, delim=';') + '}' + ';')
    )
).setParseAction(pushExclamation)
```

I've started formatting my long expressions with the operator at the beginning of the next line, this feels more readable to me. I'm guessing you might want the elements in {}'s to be kept in their own subgroup, so I grouped them. And if you want to get rid of clutter, all those semicolons look like they could be suppressed, if you structure your results suitably.

Comment: I left the semicolon exposed as a form of debugging.  Rest assured, those braces are going to become Group() and these semicolons are to be suppressed.  Trying it out now.

Comment: Found two error in the 'pass' `runTests()`; once fixed, now all but one are passing.   Will continue adding more unit test scenarios.

Comment: The only valid test content that is failing is "12.12.12.12; !13.13.13.13;".  Apparently, the exclamation mark is optionally be able to preside by each element whether it starts with a digit (IPv4/IPv6), a "key" word, or 'alphanum'.

Comment: Then you'll need to move it inside the ZeroOrMore. Glad to see you are making progress

Comment: Thank you very much, Paul. I’m now furiously banging out the easy ones now.

Comment: I may have to bump the `setParseAction(pushExclamation)` up one nested parentheses earlier, no?